# Qurbani from children having enough money!

Tags: udhiyyah

What is the rule of **Qurbani** for **children** aged below 15 years?
Monthly I give some money to my child, now he has more than $4,000
I gave Zakat but not sure about Qurbani, any proof from Quran and/or Sunnah?

Comment: Has your child reached puberty? And according to which madhab you seek an answer? [This](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/49405/) and [this](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/49546/) are relevant.

Comment: Not reached to puberty yet, I am ready to accept by any sect but must be from Quran/Hadeeth